# Wallet download checksum

Tags: wallets, hash-algorithm

I am having trouble verifying the checksum of the newest Etherum wallet download. On the download site it is not specified which hash algorithm was used to generate the checksum so on my Mac I tried.

```
openssl sha Ethereum-Wallet-macosx-0-8-3.dmg
openssl sha1 Ethereum-Wallet-macosx-0-8-3.dmg
```

even

```
openssl md5 Ethereum-Wallet-macosx-0-8-3.dmg
```

but none of them generated the checksum of

```
e915e66a774cd9af320b746bfd907cc9f678d0d39e75643f35488925e177fefa
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try SHA256. I thought that's what I did to check the latest release... can't remember. But I didn't do the PGP thing stated below.

Comment: Ah yes that's it. Don't know why I did not think about that. Thx!

Comment: Ah good, added it as an answer so this question can be marked as answered ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wallet download checksum is a SHA256 hash.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Ethereum Wallet is a PGP(Pretty Good Privacy) verified release. This is not a checksum (hash).

This is mentioned under "PGP-Verified releases" on the Ethereum github [page](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases).

There should be free resources for Mac OS for PGP validation. You can check this [tutorial](http://notes.jerzygangi.com/the-best-pgp-tutorial-for-mac-os-x-ever/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer, but I still don't get how I actually can verify my download. The PGP integration does not seem complete according to this https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/546.